# Dynamic Matrix Plot in C++ using gnuplot

Tags: c++, c++11, dynamic, plot, gnuplot

I am using gnuplot in C++. I need to plot a 2D Matrix, so I write it onto the file and then plot it using.

```
plot("plot 'mat.txt' matrix with image");
```

But the file is constantly being updated, so every time I run that command in a loop, it should read from the file again and plot, which isn't happening. I tried doing this

```
while(1)
{
    writeToFile2();
    plot("clear");
    plot("plot 'mat.txt' matrix with image");
    plot("pause 2");
    writeToFile();
    plot("replot");
    fflush(stdout);
    plot("clear");
    plot("reread");
    plot("plot 'mat.txt' matrix with image");
    plot("pause 2");
}
```

writeToFile2() and writeToFile() are two functions which write two different matrices onto mat.txt. How do I make it reread from the file properly?

Comment: Does `writeToFile()` flush the file buffer? Is that what you were trying to do with `fflush(stdout)` ?

Comment: @ChrisStathis
writeTofile has no fflush() statement. I had earlier once encountered input related issues for strings and had used fflush, so used it here, thinking it might help.

writeToFile just has a ofstream file object that opens a file and writes the array onto the file